# External DLL overriding some methods

Tags: .net, dll, external, overriding

i've created a program with certain functionality.
but i would like to Change functionality when a certain DLL is present.

i want to use this as kind of a Key system on a USB dongle.
the functionality is actually on the USB stick, and is only available when this USB dongle is present.

the moment the dongle is removed, the program loses this functionality, but keeps on working with the original functionality.

i could provide all the functionality in the original program , but i would prefer to have the functionality on the external DLL or whatever method.

Thx

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think 'overriding' the functionality is really feasible, but you could definitely design your application to make this possible. But honestly, you're making this a lot harder than it needs to be:P

EDIT: Been trying to do a demo for a while, I see it's possible, but really WAY too much trouble.